# How to organize my controllers in projects in .Net API?

Tags: c#, .net, web-api, architectural-patterns, enterprise-architecture

I'm working on a project that is a API with many controllers and modules. Which of the following is the best architectural practice to organizing my API controllers by dll (.NET 4.7 WebAPI)? Why?

*OBS: Each item is inside a module is a dll*

1. One dll for each controller. Each csproj contains only one Controller.cs file:

> **Module 1**
>     **-- API Controller 1**
>
> **-- API Controller 2**
>
> -- Domain
>     -- Application
>     -- Infra
>
> **Module 2**
>     **-- API Controller 3**
>
> **-- API Controller 4**
>
> -- Domain
>     -- Application
>     -- Infra

2. Group controllers in projects by context

> **Module 1**
>     **-- API**
>
> -- Domain
>     -- Application
>     -- Infra
>
> **Module 2**
>     **-- API**
>
> -- Domain
>     -- Application
>     -- Infra

3. Create only one csproj with all controllers.

> **Module 1**
>     -- Domain
>     -- Application
>     -- Infra
>
> **Module 2**
>     -- Domain
>     -- Application
>     -- Infra
>
> **API** (controllers)

Note: I'm using DDD (as possible), separating my business rules by context. Each context has its layers: domain, application and infra.

I started centralizing all Controllers of all contexts in one api project. It started to be messy, so I break in separate projects. However, there is some performance issue or architectural pattern that should I follow to organize my project?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this as an extension of *locality*: code should live near where it will be used, when possible. Sometimes it makes sense to break things up differently, but that's the default we generally use, right?

Similarly, if you're working on the domain model for something, you're probably going to also work on the controller code soon if you didn't already. We *know* that different layers in an N-tier architecture are going to be tied together, and it's not just by convention.

Different elements of business logic and/or the model may tie together as well, but we *know* the different layers will, so that seems like the preferential grouping to me, if you know you're going to have a lot.

That said, you're using domain-driven design, so you're going to have a very robust model that you probably want to keep together. I usually end up with a layout something like this:

- Model

  - ModelElement
  - ModelElement
- Module 1

  - Controller
  - DAL
- Module 2

  - Controller
  - DAL

I don't think I could point to any specific documents that state this as a best practice, but it's worked well for me and I hope it helps.